# How to initialize Container(ViewGroup)?

Tags: android, viewgroup

Automatically, in OnCreateView, there's:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

I want to initialize my variable as in the same way like OnCreateView in AsyncTask. 
I was able to initialize these variable :

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
            ViewGroup container;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list,
                    container, false);
```

However, i get the error that container isn't initialized! so how can i initialize it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining because you have not *initialized* the value of the variable `container` - you have only *declared* it. Initialization means you assign it a value, such as `ViewGroup container = null;`.

For your purposes, you can omit that entirely and simply pass null to the call to `inflate`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, null);
```

Comment: Well it would help a lot more if you could tell us what you're trying to do. All you asked was how to make Eclipse not complain about your method call with an uninitialized argument, and this solves that.

Comment: Ok i have asynctask in a fragment class.HOWEVER I'm accessing that asynctask from another class(fragment also) so  i want to initialize the variable in the OnPostExecute() however i wasn't able to achieve that

Comment: That tells me nothing about what you are trying to accomplish, but in general I don't recommend creating your UI in an AsyncTask. If it's being accessed by other fragments, then maybe the Fragment is not the right place for your AsyncTask (maybe the Activity would be better). Again, I don't have nearly enough information about your intended goals.

Comment: Dude, i want to initialize a listview like i initialize a widget in OnCreateView! i just want the elements like layoutinflater and ViewGroup

Comment: You don't actually need to pass in a ViewGroup unless you want the LayoutInflater to also attach the inflated View to the ViewGroup. If you *do* want to attach it, either do that programmatically after you've inflated the View, or pass in a ViewGroup in your Fragment's layout and also pass `true`. But again, my preference is to have the ListView already in the layout for the Fragment and simply set it's adapter (or add data to the adapter) after the AsyncTask runs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34780/discussion-between-android-arabia-and-karakuri)